# Error when trying to makeOrder: "Sold-From Location Code must have a value in Sales Header: Document Type=Quote"

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to create a salesOrder via the API but cannot get past this error.

I can see the field if I edit the quote in the Business Central website but I can't see how to set this field via the API (or where it is meant to come from).

I have created a "Configuration template" for the "Sales Header" and set the field there but still not working.